# Configure Gradle Plugin inside Gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to create a custom Gradle plugin that will encapsulate Checkstyle and PMD configurations. So, other projects can just apply one custom plugin without bothering about any additional configurations.

I applied `checkstyle` plugin.

```
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'checkstyle'
}
```

And then I applied it inside my custom plugin.

```java
public class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getPluginManager().apply(CheckstylePlugin.class);
    }
}
```

When I try to build the project I get an error.

```
Unable to find: config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml
```

How can I override other plugin's properties? For example, I want to change the default `checkstyle.xml` path. I can do it manually inside `build.gradle` of the plugin project itself. But in this case, other projects that apply the plugin won't have this configurations defined by default (I tested it).

### EDIT 1:

I managed to configure `checkstyle` plugin with `ChecktyleExtension`.

```java
public class MetricCodingRulesGradlePluginPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getPluginManager().apply("checkstyle");
        project.getExtensions().configure(CheckstyleExtension.class, checkstyleExtension -> {
            checkstyleExtension.setConfigFile(new File("style/checkstyle.xml"));
        });
    }
}
```

`checkstyle.xml` is placed in the plugin project. When I try to apply it within any other project, `checkstyle` searches it inside the current project directory but not the plugin's one. Is it possible to overcome this issue? I don't want users of that plugin to put any additional files inside their project.

### EDIT 2:

I put the config files to `resources` folder and tried to read the content.

```java
public class MetricCodingRulesGradlePluginPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getPluginManager().apply("checkstyle");
        project.getExtensions().configure(CheckstyleExtension.class, checkstyleExtension -> {
            URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("style/checkstyle.xml");
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
            try {
                checkstyleExtension.setConfigFile(
                    Paths.get(url.toURI())
                        .toFile()
                );
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I apply the plugin to another project, I get the following error:

```
URL: jar:file:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/jars-9/8f4176a8ae146bf601f1214b287eb805/my-plugin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/style/checkstyle.xml

Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:171)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:157)
```

Java cannot read the file from the `jar` archive for some reason. Any approaches to overcome this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to bundle the `checkstyle.xml` within your plugin's `resources` folder, so when you ship it, you can always access it from within the plugin code.

Basically, you need to put the config under `src/main/resources/checkstyle.xml` of the plugin and then access it like this:

```java
URL resourceURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("checkstyle.xml");
if (resourceURL != null) {
  File resourceFile = File(resourceURL.getFile());
  checkstyleExtension.setConfigFile(resourceFile);
}
```

Also remember, if you ship your plugin as a `.jar`, you'd need to unpack the `checkstyle.xml` into a temp file beforehand. Roughly:

```java
File temp = File.createTempFile(".checkstyle", ".xml")
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp)) {
  try (InputStream resourceStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("checkstyle.xml")) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytes = resourceStream.read(buffer);
    while (bytes >= 0) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
      bytes = resourceStream.read(buffer);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach already. And the problem is that I pack my plugin as a `jar` archive. So, when I apply the plugin to any project it can't find the referenced config file. What do you mean by "unpacking `checkstyle.xml` into a temp file"? Can you provide me with an example?

Comment: I added the `resources` folder approach that I used to the question

Comment: Updated the answer. Basically, you need to unpack your resource file into a local file on the consumer's site

Comment: I got the idea. But where exactly should I perform the copying to a temp file? As far as I understood, when `apply plugin: 'my-plugin'` statement occurs in the `build.gradle`, Gradle calls `MetricCodingRulesGradlePluginPlugin.apply` method internally. In that case, creating temp file in this method is pointless. Because it's already can't read the content from the `jar` archive.

Comment: Have you tried it? What's the error you got?