# Apply SpotBugs Gradle plugin inside the Gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to create a custom Gradle plugin that encapsulates preconfigured [PMD](https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/index.html), [Checkstyle](https://checkstyle.org/), and [SpotBugs](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin#readme) ([the link to Gradle plugin for SpotBugs](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.spotbugs)). I have already [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71204816/configure-gradle-plugin-inside-gradle-plugin) about issues with integrating PMD and Checkstyle to custom Gradle plugin. Thankfully, I managed to solve them. Anyway, new problems have arrived.

Firstly, I added SpotBugs to `depedencies` scope for `build.gradle` of my custom Gradle plugin. Look at the code snippet below:

```
implementation 'com.github.spotbugs.snom:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:5.0.14'
```

Then I applied `SpotBugs` inside `Plugin` implementation.

```java
public void apply(Project project) {
    project.getPluginManager().apply("com.github.spotbugs");
    project.getExtensions().configure(SpotBugsExtension.class, spotbugs -> {
    spotbugs.getIgnoreFailures().set(false);
    spotbugs.getShowStackTraces().set(true);
    spotbugs.getEffort().set(Effort.MAX);
    spotbugs.getReportLevel().set(Confidence.LOW);
    spotbugs.getToolVersion().set("4.7.3");
    spotbugs.getExcludeFilter().set(
        FileUtil.copyContentToTempFile("style/spotbugs_exclude.xml", ".spotbugs_exclude.xml")
    );
    ...
});
```

Unfortunately, then I add this plugin to another project, the error occurs:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.instantiation.ClassGenerationException: Could not generate a decorated class for type MetricCodingRulesGradlePluginPlugin.
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:243)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCrossBuildInMemoryCacheFactory$AbstractCrossBuildInMemoryCache.get(DefaultCrossBuildInMemoryCacheFactory.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:168)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AsmBackedClassGenerator.generate(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.Jsr330ConstructorSelector.lambda$forType$0(Jsr330ConstructorSelector.java:56)
    at org.gradle.cache.Cache.lambda$get$0(Cache.java:31)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCrossBuildInMemoryCacheFactory$AbstractCrossBuildInMemoryCache.get(DefaultCrossBuildInMemoryCacheFactory.java:130)
    at org.gradle.cache.Cache.get(Cache.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.Jsr330ConstructorSelector.forType(Jsr330ConstructorSelector.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.Jsr330ConstructorSelector.forParams(Jsr330ConstructorSelector.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.doCreate(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.instantiatePlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:81)
    ... 185 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/spotbugs/snom/SpotBugsExtension
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.inspectClass(ClassInspector.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.visitGraph(ClassInspector.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.inspect(ClassInspector.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AbstractClassGenerator.inspectType(AbstractClassGenerator.java:272)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:211)
    ... 197 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.spotbugs.snom.SpotBugsExtension
    ... 202 more
```

Seems like the `spotbugs-gradle-plugin` dependency is not being packed within the plugin-jar. Is there any workaround to fix that?

Comment: [There is a similar plugin](https://github.com/xvik/gradle-quality-plugin) that encapsulates PMD, Checkstyle, and SpotBugs. Not sure what's the difference with my approach.